# How do you decide on the dimensions for a the activation layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

The tensorflow hub docs have this example code for text classification:

```
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim50/1", output_shape=[50],
                           input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

I don't understand how we decide if 16 is the right magic number for the `relu` layer. Can someone explain this please.

Comment: The values are something at which you arrive by trying several models, with different number of units, feature extractors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of 16 units in the hidden layer is not a uniquely determined magic value. Like Shubham commented, it's all about experimenting and finding values that work well for your problem. Here is some folklore to guide your experimentation:

- The usual range for the number of units in hidden layers is tens to thousands.
- Powers of two may utilize specific hardware (like GPUs) more effectively.
- Simple feed-forward networks like the one above often decrease the number of units between successive layers. A commonly cited intuition is to progress from many basic features to fewer, more abstract ones. (Hidden layers tend to produce dense representations like embeddings, not discrete features, but the reasoning applies analogously to the dimension of the feature space.)
- The code snippet above does not show regularization. When trying whether more hidden units help, watch out for the gap between training and validation quality. A widening gap may indicate the need to regularize more.